# Typescript create class property whose value will be used as another type's property name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a class property that can be used to define another type:

```
class TypeOne {
    public static readonly key: string = 'key';
}

class TypeTwo { public [TypeOne.key]: TypeOne }
```

But it shows this error:

> A computed property name in a class property declaration must have a simple literal type or a 'unique symbol'

It works fine with the constant value of an enum:

```
enum TypeThree {
    key = 'key'
}

class TypeFour { public [TypeThree.key]: TypeThree }
```

Is there any way to set a constant value on a class so that the compiler can accept it as an immutable key and understand the field name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `string` annotation:

```
class TypeOne {
    public static readonly key = 'key';
}

class TypeTwo { public [TypeOne.key]: TypeOne }
```

TS needs a literal type for the property name, string is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define `TypeOne` as:

```
class TypeOne {
    public static readonly key = 'key'; // Remove the string annotation
}
```

This makes the value of `key` constant which is the literal string `'key'`, since this is a unique value the compiler won't complain

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgeQHbOgbwLACgBIRAVwCMQBLYaCAFzDuugCdkwATAe3RHmgDWyfgF5oAciHxxAbgIBfAgVCQYCFLADuXHNFIVmAbXVpMAOikBdAFxwkprIvxA)